# select join on almost same values

Tags: mysql

Not sure how to formulate the question. Basically I would like to join 2 columns where one is just a number and other one is 'abc/number'.

This is a sample code:

```
select b.*, a.*
from business b join
 activity a
 on b.primary_activity_id = a.id
where ...;
```

a.id = 3 and b.primary_activity_id = abc/3
How to do a match in this case?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `like`:

```
select b.*, a.*
from business b 
join activity a
    on b.primary_activity_id like concat('%/', a.id)
where ...
```

Comment: This allows for anything to be before the "/".  If it is specifically abc, then use that literal; it will be a lot faster.